# R can't stem my corpus

Tags: r, nlp, stemming

I am following [this tutorial](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.com/2013/03/build-search-engine-in-20-minutes-or.html) on building a complete search

They say:

```
library(Snowball)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stemDocument)
my.corpus$doc1
```

But as far as I can see Snowball as well as SnowballC are deprecated.
I tried RStem but it gives me error for the corpus... How can I stem my corpus?

```
#load
my.docs <- VectorSource(c(doc.list, query))
my.docs$Names <- c(names(doc.list), "query")

my.corpus <- Corpus(my.docs)

my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removePunctuation)

# HOW TO STEM?????
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, removeNumbers)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, tolower)
my.corpus <- tm_map(my.corpus, stripWhitespace)

inspect(my.corpus)
```

Comment: Try install.packages("SnowballC"); library(SnowballC).

Comment: What is the error message?